# overriding equals method when dealing with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, equals, abstraction

I have been reading about how best to override the equals method when dealing with subclasses and here I have found quite a few posts. They recommend different ways of implementing a solution using instanceof or getClass() to compare objects of different sub classes.

However with reference to Effective Java, my understanding is (and I am new to this so I may well be wrong!) Bloch argues that in the end both can be problematic, “There is no way to extend an instantiable class and add a value component while preserving the equals contract, unless you are willing to forgo the benefits of object-oriented abstraction”. Then recommends to “favour composition over inheritance”.

So I am dealing with this class hierarchy: AbstractClass, ConcreteClass1 and ConcreteClass2. ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractClass and ConcreteClass2 extends ConcreteClass1. At the moment only AbstractClass overrides the equals method.

So in AbstractClass:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
        private String id;


        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            return other != null && other.getClass().equals(getClass())
                    && id.equals(((AbstractClass) other).id);
        }

    }
```

And in ConcreteClass1 I have:

```
public class ConcreteClassOne extends AbstractClass
{
  private final AbstractClass parent;

  public ConcreteClassOne( String anId, AbstractClass aParent )
  {
    super( anId );

    parent = aParent;
  }

}
```

Finally in ConcreteClassTwo I have:

```
public class ConcreteClassTwo extends ConcreteClassOne
{
  private static int nextTrackingNo = 0;

  private final int trackingNo;

  public ConcreteClassTwo ( String anId )
  {
    super( anId, null );

    trackingNo= getNextTrackingNo();
  }
}
```

So I believe I need to override equals method in both ConcreteClassOne and ConcreteClassTwo to include the significant fields parent and trackingNo. I'm not allowed to change the design so using composition is not an option. Any suggestions?

Comment: So... What's the question/problem? There is nothing wrong with overriding the equals method.

Comment: The question is about overriding equals while respecting its contract.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you got my point!

Comment: FYI: [Angelika Langer - Secrets of equals](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals.html)

Comment: @McDowell thanks, I'd come across that one but frankly still haven't had a chance to study it fully.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to extend equals() in both the concrete and the abstract classes.

```
public class ConcreteClassTwo extends ConcreteClassOne {
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        boolean rv = super.equals( other );
        if ( other instanceof ConcreteClassTwo ) {
           rv = rv && (this.trackingNo == ((ConcreteClassTwo) other).trackingNo);
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And with regards to instanceof and getClass(), am I right to say it's safer to stick to getClass()? i.e. objects of two different subclasses should never be the same. let say if I extend ConcreteClass1 to have ConcreteClass3, objects created from CC2 and CC3 are not equal even if they have the same content.

Comment: @user2397607 - In your case, yes. In general, Bloch prefers instanceof to getClass(), to support trivial subclasses that don't add any state. But here, reflexivity is satisfied with your implementation of AbstractClass.equals() and my implementation of ConcreteClassTwo.equals(). With these, c1.equals(c2) == c2.equals(c1).

Comment: But you are breaking transitivity, so nothing much is gained here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik so is Bloch's "composition over inheritance" the ultimate the last solution? i.e. as it stands, this is a design rather than implementation issue.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I was correcting your earlier comment on this answer. Can you provide an example of the transitivity issue you're seeing? [Edit: Added missing return statement.]

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer spotted that one :)

Comment: If you have `c2a`, `c1`, and `c2b` (instances of ConcreteClassTwo, One, and Two, respectively), you can have `c2a.equals(c1)` and `c1.equals(c2b)` without guaranteeing `c2a.equals(c2b)`.

Comment: You appear to be mistaken. See http://ideone.com/3yMrU8. That said, my preferences would be (in order) to avoid this problem by making non-leaf classes abstact; else avoid adding a value component in a subclass of a concrete class; else use getClass() in preference to instanceof throughout the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `equals` both in `ConcreteClassOne` and `ConcreteClassTwo` then the symmetry of `equals` is broken:

```
Object c1 = new ConcreteClassOne(),
       c2 = new ConcreteClassTwo();
System.out.println("c1=c2? " + c1.equals(c2)");
System.out.println("c2=c1? " + c2.equals(c1)");
```

Now, if you implement `equals` the usual way, this is going to print

```
true
false
```

because in `c2.equals` you have `instanceof ConcreteClassTwo`, which fails for `c1`, but in the opposite case the analogous check passes.

Comment: Yes, I thought you needed additional explanation/confirmation of that point. Bloch is right and there's nothing you can do except allowing equality only on the condition `a.getClass()==b.getClass()`.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned I am new to the concept so confirmation of what I understood from Bloch's point is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The base class contract should specify one of two approaches: either it should declare that no derived-class object should consider itself to any other object that is not of the *exact same class*, or else it should specify that every derived-class object should be convertible to a canonical form defined by the base-class contract, and two immutable objects should be considered equivalent if their canonical forms would match.

An example of the latter situation would be an ImmutableSquareFloatMatrix base class with methods `int GetSize()` and `float GetCell(int row, int column)`.  A common implementation would have an array of (size*size) float values in it, but one could also have e.g. `ZeroMatrix` and `IdentityMatrix` classes whose only field specified the size, a `ConstantMatrix` class with a field specifying the size and a field specifying a value which should be returned for every cell, a `DiagonalMatrix` class with a single-dimensional array just containing items for the diagonal (the `GetCell` method would return zero for everything else), etc.

Given two instances of classes derived from `ImmutableSquareFloatMatrix`, it would be possible to compare them by comparing their sizes and then comparing all the values therein, but that would in many cases be inefficient.  If either of the objects being compared "knows" about the other object's type, it may be possible to improve efficiency enormously.  If neither object knows about the other, falling back to a default comparison method may be slow, but would yield correct results in any case.

A workable approach to handle that situation may be to have the base type implement an `equals2` method, which return 1 if its special knowledge of the other object meant it could tell it was equal, -1 if it could tell it was not equal, or 0 if it couldn't tell.  If either type's `equals2` method knows they're unequal, they're unequal.  Otherwise, if either knows they're equal, they're equal.  Otherwise, test equality using cell-by-cell comparison.